# Blurry Text During Transform On Some Elements Webkit

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a web-app that has some simple, nice transition effects when hovering over buttons or focusing on form fields.

If the form field is in a regular div on the page and you focus on it the form field 'pops out' just fine and there are no problems.

However when the form field is in a lightbox that pops up during the transition on the hover all of the text in the lightbox goes blurry. It stops being blurry once the transform is complete.

Some examples for you:

```
<div>
    <b>First Name:</b>
    <input type="text">
<div>
```

The above works fine. When focusing on the text field it will 'popout' `transform: translate(-2px,-2px);` just fine with no blurring at all.

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="lightbox-content">
        <b>Option 1:</b>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above does not work fine. During the `transform: translate(-2px,-2px)` all of the text/elements, etc in that lightbox go blurry for the 0.5s of the transition.

Here are the styles I'm currently using:

```
.lightbox {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 transform: translateY(-105%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-105%);
 transition: transform 0.001s, opacity 0.75s;
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.001s, opacity 0.75s;
 opacity: 0;
}

.lightbox-content {
 max-height: 80%; 
 overflow: auto; 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 50%; 
 left: 50%; 
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background: white;
 border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

You can view a simple jsfiddle here.. https://jsfiddle.net/uneeuh08/ It may not be great code because I copied and pasted just what I needed to show it. It's not as bad on the jsfiddle site as it is on our site for some reason but it's still there a little. Just bugging me.

Comment: Can you provide us some working code snippet?

Comment: @Subgeo I've added the jsfiddle link.. you can find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/uneeuh08/ - It's not as bad on jsfiddle as it is on our site but it's still there and noticeable. It seems to only do it on webkit... It may have to do with the `.lightbox-content` class because when I remove the transform from that class (the one that centers the lightbox content on the page) all of the blurring goes away completely... 

Is there another way to get a div to center completely on the page?

Comment: Thank you, I understood the question now and answered it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uneeuh08/1/)**.

You can use *`display`*`: flex;` property combined with *`align-items`*`: center;` and *`justify-content`*`: center;`.

Your CSS classes will become:

```
.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-105%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-105%);
    transition: transform 0.001s, opacity 0.75s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.001s, opacity 0.75s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.lightbox-content {
     max-height: 80%; 
     overflow: auto; 
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0;
     background: white;
     border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Notice the `margin: 0;` property. Flexbox can perfectly center your contents in the page if you add it.

Comment: That did it! Sorry for the delayed response I've been pretty busy and haven't had time to fiddle with it yet. Thank you!